# How do I manage custom modules?

Tags: 7, composer

I have planned to use Composer to manage Drupal core and third-party modules instead of pushing everything to Git and I am using [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/tree/7.x) to achieve it.

After running `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:7.x-dev d7 --stability dev --no-interaction`, a *d7* directory is created with some other directories, including the following ones.

- vendor
- web (It contains the Drupal core files.)

Its composer.json file is enough to install the same dependencies in another server, but if I use `composer install` in my server, how can I checkout my custom modules?

If I add custom modules and the composer.json file only in my repository, where do the custom modules go when I run during `composer install`? Do they go in sites/all/custom or the root directory?

Is there any other option available to manage my custom modules with Composer?

Comment: What does "custom module" mean? The contributed module from drupal.org or the module that you create yourself.

Comment: modules that are created by myself.

Comment: I'm on the same page and found this for a starting point: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/managing-dependencies-for-a-custom-project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contributed modules are in `web/sites/all/modules/contrib/`.

So, the suggested directory for the custom modules is `web/sites/all/modules/custom/`.

The other way to manage custom modules is to separate repository for the custom modules.

You can add your custom repositories to your `composer.json` in project root directory. Composer will look in all your repositories to find the packages your project requires. See [Use PHP composer to clone git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954051/use-php-composer-to-clone-git-repo). Add your repositories under default `Drupal`.

After you add your repository to `composer.json` you have to tell Composer to install your custom modules to `web/sites/all/modules/custom/`. Add this line to `installer-paths`

```
"web/sites/all/modules/custom/{$name}/": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
```

When you create your custom module, you must set type of your custom module in `composer.json`  to `drupal-custom-module`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it will need two repo to maintain changes in composer json and custom modules. right?
Because if i use git repo only for my custom modules, then updates in composer has to be tracked in another repo as that file will be used in server using install command.
Please correct me if  I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, composer file in site root needs to be tracked. These are same steps as installing contributed module. Additions are adding your own repo and custom modules directory.